# Error while uploading large size image

Tags: php, html

I got error while I'm trying to upload large image. I'm new in php, Please guide me or provide me a better way to code it.

I got these error messages

```
Warning: mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test.php on line 63

Warning: mysql_query(): Error reading result set's header in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test.php on line 63
```

Problem uploding the image. Please check your database

Here is my code

```
<?php

//connect to the database//
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "root");
if(!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect to the database:' . mysql_error());
 echo "ERROR IN CONNECTION";
}

$sel = mysql_select_db("forms1");
if(!$sel)
{
die('Could not connect to the database:' . mysql_error());
echo "ERROR IN CONNECTION";
}
//file properties//

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 

$upload=0;

*/for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES['image']); $count++)
{
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'][$count])){
   $image_desc[$count] = addslashes($_POST['imageDescription'][$count]);
   $image_name[$count] = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name'][$count]); echo '<br \>';
   $image_size[$count] = @getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count]);
   $error[$count] = $_FILES['image']['error'][$count];

   if($image_size[$count] === FALSE  || ($image_size[$count]) == 0)
       echo "That's not an image";

   $upload++;
   echo $upload;

// Temporary file name stored on the server
    $tmpName[$count]  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count];

// Read the file
   $fp[$count]   = fopen($tmpName[$count], 'r');
   $data[$count] = fread($fp[$count], filesize($tmpName[$count]));
   $data[$count] = addslashes($data[$count]);
   fclose($fp[$count]);


// Create the query and insert into database.
$results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO files( name, image) VALUES('$image_desc[$count]','$data[$count]')", $con);

    if(!$results)
    echo "Problem uploding the image. Please check your database";  
}

?>
```

Comment: just my two cents: Please don't use the mysql_* functions. They are not supported anymore and will be removed from PHP eventually. Read about MySQLi or PDO. About the upload, someone else will provide a good answer!

Comment: how big is your image exactly?

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on your local server you have to change your php.ini file

here are the steps from: 
http://alex-lanos.blogspot.com/2012/09/xampp-apache-php-how-to-increase-upload.html

Create a file under public_html and name it php.ini (if you do not have one yet.) Put the following in it:
upload_max_filesize = 5M
post_max_size = 5M
Replace the 5 with 20 or less. If you are letting other people upload, a size cap protects your storage space from abuse/overuse.
You will then need to add this line to a .htaccess file: (Please replace "yourusername" with your cpanel user name an add to the end of the comand line the folder(s) to the location of the php.ini file - Also there is a space between path and /home)
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/Yourusername/public_html
Now your PHP upload limit should be increased.

Comment: there might be more than one folder with the php.ini file make sure you change all of them.